# useEffect React Hook calls multiple times when a component changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks, use-effect

My function makes 10 async calls to the backend when the filterState has been changed. I want it to be called once per change.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const getQuery = async () => {
      let query = filterActions.getQueryString()
      taskService.get(query).then(res => {
        console.log('tasks res', res)
        setQueriedTasks(res)
      })
    }

    getQuery()
  }, [filterState])
```

How I update the filter

```
  const updateFilter = (updates) => {
    dispatch({type: 'SET_FILTER', payload: updates})
  }
```

My reducer to update state

```
function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
  case 'SET_FILTER':
    return Object.assign({...state}, action.payload)
  }
}
```

Comment: Add code where you are updating filterState

Comment: debounce it maybe?

Comment: I have edited my question with more code

Comment: instead of `[filterState]`  check it with `[JSON.stringfy(filterState)]`.

Comment: Could you provide a codesandbox that shows the code with a bit more context?